# How to set if else with jQuery on hide show functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery toggle button but I don't want to use toggleslide. If it is loaded homepage, the div must be opened and have a button to hide.
But if it is loaded another page, div must be closed and have button to show
HEre is two code, that doesn't work. I try to add them together in HTML but doesn't work

For homepage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip").click(function(){
    if(window.location.href == 'http://homepage/')
       $("#panel").hide("fast");
   }); 
});
```

for another page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip").click(function(){
    if(window.location.href != 'http://homepage/')
       $("#panel").show("fast");
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Please create a snippet of your problem

Comment: Can you show the html of your button?

Comment: This is html code. FLip div is the button: <div id="flip">bla</div> <div id="panel"> bla </div>

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. I am taking input just to show you a demo.

```js
var x = prompt("Whichpage is this ? ");
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(x == 'http://homepage/')
    $("#panel").show("fast");
  else
    $("#panel").hide("fast");
});

$("#flip").click(function(){
  $("#panel").toggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">I am a panel</div>
<button id="flip">Flip</button>
```

For your case just set `var x = window.location.href`

Comment: This is html code. FLip div is the button:

<div id="flip">bla</div>
<div id="panel"> bla </div>